# ASR not recognising IP addresses of VMware VMs as valid after creating protection group

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine, virtualization

While performing ASR migration from VMWare Vsphere VMs to azure portal, I have reached till creating a protection group step in [azure portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/site-recovery-vmware-to-azure/#step-7-create-a-protection-group).

The configuration server, master target, process server and Vcenter Host server are all up and running in azure and are shown as "Healthy" and in sync.

But while adding the on premise VMWare Virtual Machines to the protection group, its showing their IP addresses as invalid. Also mobility service is installed on the VMs (manually), still it is showing in the portal as not installed.

My Network reference:
Azure IP Range: 10.99.18.0/24
On-Prem VMware VM's: 10.209.113.0/24
Connection from On-Prem to Azure is VPN/express route.
both end-to-end are able to connect each other.

The IPs of the VMs are now public and outside any firewall.

**Error Screenshot from Azure ASR:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install the VMWare tools by downloading them local on the vm or network drive. Once installed it will ask for restart. Wait for replication to take effect for about 15 min minimum with enhanced version. Now you should not see any error.
Regards
Ravichander Pinnaca